# Is raw socket on loopback interface possible?

Tags: linux, sockets, raw-sockets

We are trying to communicate with the server listening on Linux loopback interface via raw socket and it seems like the server does not get a single packet from us. The packets we send are visible in Wireshark.

Is raw socket on loopback possible at all? (Please, don't ask why we need it: it's too complicated to explain here)

EDIT: this is how we open it

```
_I_RawSocket = socket( PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)))

memset( &ifr, 0, sizeof( ifr ) );
strcpy( ifr.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, _InterfaceName);

ioctl( _I_RawSocket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr )

memset( &sll, 0, sizeof( sll ) );
sll.sll_family   = AF_PACKET;
sll.sll_ifindex  = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
sll.sll_protocol = htons( ETH_P_ALL );

bind( _I_RawSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &sll, sizeof( sll ))
```

The server is lighttpd and it's reachable via normal socket on localhost.
netstat --raw prints empty table but I'm absolutely sure we have two functional raw sockets on normal eth devices.

Comment: Please post: a) Exactly what type of socket you are using, is it a AF_PACKET ? b) How you are binding it, are you using bind or SO_BINDTODEVICE ? c) What is the server and what is it trying to do? Can you talk to it with an IP socket (assuming IP here)? Can you send the output of netstat --raw ?

Comment: @MarkR: Given that he's going for raw sockets, I'm guessing SOCK_RAW. SOCK_PACKET is obsolete, anyway.

Comment: I find the "man 7 packet" page quite useful, please read it and see if what it describes is consistent with what you're doing.

Comment: @mfukar I meant AF_PACKET not the obsolete "AF_INET/SOCK_RAW"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw sockets behave particularly fizzy with bind() and connect(), but I can't confirm that your issue lies with them. I suggest you follow a more straightforward approach:

Sender

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEST "127.0.0.1"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

 int s;
 struct sockaddr_in dst_addr;
 char packet[50];

 struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *)packet;  

 if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0) {
  perror("error:");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 dst_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 dst_addr.sin_port = 0; /* not needed in SOCK_RAW */
 inet_pton(AF_INET, DEST, (struct in_addr *)&dst_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
 memset(dst_addr.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(dst_addr.sin_zero));

 memset(packet, 'A', sizeof(packet));   /* payload will be all As */

 ip->ihl = 5;
 ip->version = 4;
 ip->tos = 0;
 ip->tot_len = htons(40);
 ip->frag_off = 0;  /* NF */
 ip->ttl = 64;
 ip->protocol = IPPROTO_RAW; /* this has to be IPPROTO_RAW */
 ip->check = 0;
 ip->saddr = dst_addr.sin_addr.s_addr;
 ip->daddr = dst_addr.sin_addr.s_addr;

 while(42) {
  sleep(5);
  if (sendto(s, packet, sizeof(packet), 0, 
   (struct sockaddr *)&dst_addr, (socklen_t)sizeof(dst_addr)) < 0)
   perror("uh oh:");
 }
 return(0);
}
```

Receiver

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 int s;
 struct sockaddr_in src_addr;
 char packet[50];

 if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0) {
  perror("error:");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 memset(packet, 0, sizeof(packet));
 socklen_t *len = (socklen_t *)sizeof(src_addr);
 int fromlen = sizeof(src_addr);

 while(42) {
  if (recvfrom(s, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0,
   (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr, &fromlen) < 0)
   perror("uh oh:");

  int i = sizeof(struct iphdr); /* print the payload */
  for(; i < sizeof(packet); i++) {
   printf("%c", packet[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
 return(0);
}
```

I hope these behave exactly like you want them to. Read `man 7 raw` for the gory details of why this works and **more importantly** `man 7 packet` if you want to extend it. Also, take note that IPPROTO_RAW implies the IP_HDRINCL socket option, which is why we're constructing the ip header ourselves - although the IP checksum and total length are computed and filled in by the kernel, still.

edit: In addition, if you wanted a raw socket with which to send valid data to an application like lighttpd, you'd have to match the `protocol` argument to `socket()` as well as provide valid values for the IP header fields. A proper ethernet header is not mandatory - the only important field will be filled for you by the kernel stack.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure bind to if_index

```
if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFINDEX, &stEthReq ) < 0 )
{
    printf( "failed to get IF index!" );
    return -1;
}
memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));
client_addr.sll_family   = AF_PACKET;
client_addr.sll_ifindex  = stEthReq.ifr_ifru.ifru_ivalue;
client_addr.sll_protocol = VOS_HTONS(usEthType);
ret = bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)(&client_addr), sizeof(client_addr));
```